# Solving for A in the system Ax = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the system of linear equations $A x = 0$ where $A$ is a $K \times M$ matrix of reals and $x$ is an $M \times 1$ vector of reals. The matrix $A$ is unknown but we can generate $x$s that satisfy this system of equations.

My questions are:

1) What are the conditions on $A$ that allow us to generate $A$ using choices of $x$? For example, if $A$ is $3 \times 3$ and nonsingular then the only choice of $x$ that satisfies the equation is $x=(0 \ 0 \ 0)'$ and so we can't generate $A$ using different choices of $x$. Hence, we require $M>K$ and in fact I think for each free variable we can generate $K$ equations.

2) Assuming there are choices of $x$ that generate $A$, what is the ''best'' way to choose $x$ and can you express $A$ in terms of the choices of $x$? ''Best'' can be interpreted as easiest to understand or satisfy some other quality.

I would appreciate a link to a paper or notes.

This question is related to [Methods to solve a system of many Ax=B equations using least-squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232118/methods-to-solve-a-system-of-many-ax-b-equations-using-least-squares)